# Update binding on WPF Datagrid hover

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a simple WPF datagrid in an MVVM design that is bound to a `List<Object>`.  My goal is to update one of the properties when the user hovers over that row.  I've been investigating style triggers, interaction.trigger, and just can't seem to find something that works.  Thanks for the help!

The model:

```
public class CarrierInvDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    private bool _IsHover;
    public bool IsHover
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsHover;
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged.ChangeAndNotify(ref _IsHover, value, () => IsHover);
        }
    }
}
```

The Viewmodel:

```
private List<CarrierInvDetails> _CarrierInvList;
public List<CarrierInvDetails> CarrierInvList
{
    get
    {
        return _CarrierInvList;
    }
    set
    {
        PropertyChanged.ChangeAndNotify(ref _CarrierInvList, value, () => CarrierInvList);
    }
}
```

The View:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CarrierInvList}" 
            Margin="5"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCarrierInv}"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <!--This is kind of what Id like to do.  When the mouse is over the row, update IsHover to True, but it complains about having a "Binding" here -->
                    <Setter Property="{Binding IsHover}" Value="True"/> 
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: setters have different purpose. what are you going to do with IsHover property in the viewmodel?

Comment: @ASh I'm looking to handle some logic and possibly update other properties with it.  The thing is, I'd like to track IsSelected and IsHover separately.  The Setter example was just an attempt to show how I'd like or expect the solution to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the future, I was able to get a working solution by using a combination of Events, interface, and Style triggers.

First, setting the datagrid style:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.DataGridRow}">
        <!-- This is where we will set the IsHover property -->
        <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="DataGridRow_Enter" /> 
        <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="DataGridRow_Leave" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHover}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSeaGreen"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The interface:

```
public interface IHover
{
    public bool IsHover
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then the code-behind that actually sets the values

```
private void DataGridRow_Enter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender.GetType() != typeof(DataGridRow))
        return;

    if (typeof(Models.IHover).IsAssignableFrom((sender as DataGridRow).DataContext.GetType()))
    {
        ((Models.IHover)((sender as DataGridRow).DataContext)).IsHover = true;
    }
}

private void DataGridRow_Leave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender.GetType() != typeof(DataGridRow))
        return;

    if (typeof(Models.IHover).IsAssignableFrom((sender as DataGridRow).DataContext.GetType()))
    {
        ((Models.IHover)((sender as DataGridRow).DataContext)).IsHover = false;
    }
}
```

And finally the model that utilizes the interface

```
public class ClientInvDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged, IHover
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _IsHover;
    public bool IsHover
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsHover;
        }
        set
        {
            //This is simply an extension that handles the notification of a property change.  You can use a standard "OnPropertyChanged" function that is available elsewhere
            PropertyChanged.ChangeAndNotify(ref _IsHover, value, () => IsHover);
        }
    }

    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged.ChangeAndNotify(ref _IsSelected, value, () => IsSelected);
        }
    }
}
```